Missing Settings Multitasking
Hello i am completely missing the Multitasking option in my settings.
I can't create additional workspaces too by dragging apps in the app-view.
Which packages do i have to reinstall?
Thanks for the help and recommendations.
I am running:
Ubuntu : 20.04.6
Gnome :   3.36.8

Why would you need to install any packages? Your question appears to say they were installed, how did they get removed?
